# How do i arrange the contents of a file in numerical order?

Tags: c#

I've got these lines of code which reads a file and supposed to put the last digits on the line in number order:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"g:\\myfile.DAT");
var result = lines.AsParallel()
    .OrderBy(s => s.Split('>').Last())
    .ToList();
result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

But its got decimal places in the answer. It works (sort of) but its putting `11` before `3.75`. What have I done wrong?

Comment: It's sorting that way because they are strings - if you want them to sort in numerical order, they will have to be parsed as numbers.

Comment: You have to convert elements to decimal.

Comment: Even if the line contains text?

Comment: Would you mind adding a sample of what the file contents could look like? That could give people an idea of what to expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding Convert.ToDouble into your OrderBy you can achieve your goal:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"g:\\myfile.DAT");
var result = lines.AsParallel()
                  .OrderBy(s => Convert.ToDouble(s.Split('>').Last()))
                  .ToList();
result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

More info on [Convert.ToDouble](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Unless there is text in between. So you could have to break it into pieces and capture potential parsing errors. This information is not in the original question though.

Comment: I thought it only sorted the lines out after the ">" which contains just numbers thats why I didn't state it originally, sorry.

Comment: how do I write these results to a text file instead of the console as  File.WriteAllText(@"g:\\myfile.DAT", Result); doesn't seem to work